# Axiom Not Returning Depending On Contents of Json

Tags: python, json, reactjs, flask, axiom

I have an Python Flask api that is being called in a React app using Axiom. I'm using the following code in NameForm component to handle requests from my Flask api. 
    import React from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {

    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/'+this.state.value,)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data); 
    console.log(response.status); 

  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

This code sometimes returns nothing and sometimes returns the contents from my Flask API depending on what content I generate on the backend.

Here is my backend code. For all requests, I see the request being made on the backend and see the data being printed. However, for some requests, I don't see anything returned to the front-end. The request that returns something when I have the first function is_original, but when I include the other functions below, I see nothing on the front-end. I'm very confused as to why some json is being returned while some other json is not being returned.

```
import json
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from dog_matcher import *
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/api/<name>")
def hello(name):
    data = {}
    name = name.capitalize()
    data['is_original']= is_original(name, names_file[1:10])
    data['meta_names']= get_metaphone_closest(name, names_file)
    data['leven_names'] = get_levenshtein_closest(name, names_file)
    data['jaro_names']= get_jaro_closest(name, names_file)
    data['soundex']= get_soundex_closest(name, names_file)
    print(data)
    return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

On the server, the following content is printed for the request "Jim" from the front-end. Nothing is returned on the frontend.

> {'meta_names': [(0, 'Jaime'), (0, 'Jammy'), (0, 'Jamy'), (0, 'Jayme'),
>   (0, 'Gim'), (0, 'Gimmo'), (0, 'Gimmy'), (0, 'Gimo'), (0, 'Jim'), (0,
>   'Jimmi')], 'is_original': True, 'leven_names': [(1.0, 'Jim'),
>   (0.9166666666666666, 'Jimy'), (0.8666666666666667, 'Jaime'),
>   (0.8666666666666667, 'Jimbo'), (0.8666666666666667, 'Jimmi'),
>   (0.8666666666666667, 'Jimmy'), (0.8333333333333334, 'Jaimie'),
>   (0.8095238095238096, 'Jim-Jim'), (0.7777777777777777, 'Gim'),
>   (0.7777777777777777, 'Kim')], 'jaro_names': [(1.0, 'Jim'),
>   (0.9166666666666666, 'Jimy'), (0.8666666666666667, 'Jaime'),
>   (0.8666666666666667, 'Jimbo'), (0.8666666666666667, 'Jimmi'),
>   (0.8666666666666667, 'Jimmy'), (0.8333333333333334, 'Jaimie'),
>   (0.8095238095238096, 'Jim-Jim'), (0.7777777777777777, 'Gim'),
>   (0.7777777777777777, 'Kim')], 'soundex': [(0, 'Jahn'), (0, 'Jan'), (0,
>   'Jann'), (0, 'Jean'), (0, 'Jim'), (0, 'Jin'), (0, 'Jiwan'), (0,
>   'Johann'), (0, 'John'), (0, 'Jon')]}
>   127.0.0.1 - - [26/Apr/2017 00:08:26] "GET /api/Jim HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: What's the `print(data)` content?

Comment: Added the content above.

Comment: Can you get this data in your frontend?

Comment: No. I can get {'is_original': True}
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Apr/2017 00:12:32] "GET /api/test HTTP/1.1" 200 - on my front-end though

Comment: So, in other words, whether it works on the frontend depends on what is outputted from the backend.

Comment: So, make sure you generate the data you want before return it to front end.

Comment: Right the data is being properly generated on the backend, but it is not being returned to the front-end depending on the contents on the data.

Comment: Could this be an issue related to the time of execution? Could this timeout?

Comment: Check the `response.data`. It might be something wrong in the process of `jsonify`.

Comment: I don't think so. The response looks fine when I directly access the API url in Chrome. It just doesn't return on front-end react code.

Comment: I'm not sure why but after adding event.preventDefault(); below my axios code, it now works.